# What does the following assignment of variable do

Tags: shell

I am trying to understand a bash script. I couldn't understand a piece of code. I wasn't sure what to google for either. So I'm posting it here. What does it do?

```
VARIABLE=${VARIABLE:-foo}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It assigns to VARIABLE:

- Whatever is in `$VARIABLE` if it's not unset
- `foo` otherwise

This is sometimes called a ["default" parameter](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

> ```
> ${parameter-default}, ${parameter:-default}
> ```
>
> If parameter not set, use default.

Answer (score 0):

If `VARIABLE` is not set, **or is set to the empty string**, then it sets `VARIABLE` to `foo`.

Otherwise, it effectively leaves `VARIABLE` alone, by setting it to its existing value.

The colon makes it treat the empty string as if `VARIABLE` is not set. If you say `${VARIABLE-foo}`, it expands to `$VARIABLE` even if `VARIABLE` is set the empty string. This version only expands to `foo` if `VARIABLE` is not set at all.